# Calling Specific Values From a Data Frame in Shiny Not Returning Single Records

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I have a few data frames I am using to match responses with corresponding values for a reactive select input menu. Example:

```
   City       Country
1  New York   USA
2  Chicago    USA
3  London     United Kingdom
```

I've written the below code that allows users to select a country, and then in a below reactive selectinput(), choose the city/cities that correspond to said country selection.

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

CountryX <- reactive(input$country)

observe({
updateSelectInput(session, "city",
                choices = (df[(df$`Country` == CountryX()),1]))})
```

UI:

```
selectInput(inputId = "country", label = ("Select Country"), 
            choices = sort(unique(c(as.character(df$`Country`)))), 
            selected = NULL),  

selectInput(inputId = "city", label = ("Select City"), ""),
```

The problem I am running into is with unique Country records. If I were to run the above data frame example through this code I would see both "New York" and "Chicago" in the city menu after selecting "USA" for country. But if I select "United Kingdom" as my country, I would not see "London" as an option, rather I would only get the column header, in this case "City" as an option in the City menu.

The "City" column header appears greyed out when I select a country with multiple cities, and the menu starts on the first city in the df that matches the country. Why can't I get countries with only one corresponding city listed in my data to show up in the city menu, and why do I only see the Column Header "City" as an option? Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Not sure whats wrong, but it is showing the right options based on `Country` selected.

Comment: Your code seems to work perfectly fine.